# RabbitMQ - Continuous connection between producer and consumer

Tags: php, rabbitmq, message-queue, php-amqp

I have a question - How to keep continuous connection between consumer and producer?

I mean when producer sends messages - consumer process it and send back with callback queue if I used rpc procedure and connection will closed.

Now I want connection between consumer and producer should be open. How to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. Both consumer(s) and producer(s) connects to broker, not to each other. If you don't want to close connection and have consumer(s) active and waiting for new message just keep them alive.

Comment: Yes my consumer is active - Actually I know that both consumer and producer connects to RabbitMQ asynchronously. but I want connection between consume and producer open so that if I want to send messages to producer, then I can send messages through that open connection which I want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html) can help you, you can **create a single callback queue per client**，but be careful to deal with the **correlationId** when you send message to producer.